# XmlDocument.Load error

Tags: c#, exception, xmldocument

Using C#, XmlDocument.Load is throwing this exception: "hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character".

What's confusing me is it works find in development. What differences should I be looking for on the remote server vs my development environment?

Comment: can you post the xml being loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I'd look at is: are they running **exactly** the same version of .NET? If your server is running 2.0 SP1, and your "devenv" is VS2008 SP1 (i.e. .NET 3.5 SP1), then they are **not** 100% the same, and there can be subtle differences **even** when just using the 2.0 dlls (i.e. the things that have been fixed / changed in service-packs).

The second thing I'd look at is: are they processing the same input data?

The third thing I'd look at is "culture"; is your dev machine set to French, and your server to Russian? (or something). Unlikely in this case, but in the *general* case different cultures and default-encodings / codesets can make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like a data issue. Specifically that there is an unescaped < in the file

A < can be escaped as `&lt;`

Answer (score 0):

The odd are that the content its trying to parse is the source of the error - i.e. your local dev/test data isn't the same as the live data and its the live *data* that's causing the problem.

You need to run *exactly* the data that's causing the problem on the live system through a local instance of the app - if you still don't get the error then the next question will be how are the two different.